# My Handlebars scripts aren't being processed

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm learning to use Ember for develop web applications. Like you can see, my test code just shows a text in the view.

When I use `ember-1.0.pre.js` , it works fine, but when i change to `ember-1.0.0-pre.2.js`, the next error appears: `Uncaught Error: "<TestApp.ApplicationView:ember177> - Unable to find template "application"`.  With the last version of ember : `ember-latest.js`, there are no errors , but the text doesn't appear. In the last two cases , when I inspect the generated html, I realize that  the handlebars scripts aren't being  processed and remain with the html in browser.

In the [Ember Blog](http://emberjs.com/blog/2012/10/25/ember-1-0-pre2/), they list the changes between version, but apparently theres nothing  related with my problem.

What should I change to this simple code works?.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-1.0.pre.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-1.0.0-pre.2.js"></script>-->
    <!--  <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js"></script>-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Application</h1>
    <script  type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
        {{outlet}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
        <h3> {{view.text}}</h3>
    </script>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
TestApp = Ember.Application.create();
TestApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
TestApp.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
});
TestApp.TestController = Ember.Controller.extend();
TestApp.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
    text: 'This is a sample text',
    templateName: 'test'
});
TestApp.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('test');
            }
        })
    })
});
TestApp.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting up your router thus:

```
App.Router.map(function(match){
  match('/').to('application',function(match){
    match('/').to('test')
  });
});

App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        this.render('test', {
            into:'application'
        });
})
```

And see if that helps at all

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've edited my code like you suggest me except , for the last line, I think it must be inside the renderTemplate method and after of this_super(controller,model), but still not working and doesn't appears errors . I'm using ember-last.js. Any other advice you could give me?

Comment: He said he was using `ember-1.0.pre.js` or `ember-1.0.0-pre.2.js` which wouldn't have the new router API.